# How to execute a Java 11 jar with only Java 8 installed?

Tags: java

I'm trying to execute a jar on a server, like so: `java -jar file.jar`
but I get the following error:

```
A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again 
... 
Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment (class file version 55.0), 
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0.
```

I understand this seems to relate to the fact that my jar file uses Java 11, while the server only has Java 8 installed. I cannot install Java 11 as people suggest on other posts treating this issue, since I'm executing on a server on which I am not super user. I also would like to avoid reprogramming my whole project with Java 8.

Is there a way for me to execute my jar file anyways?

Comment: If you have control of the build processs you could try set the java target version as 8, of cause source version would need to be 8 too and you would loose access to features from java 9 onwards

Comment: You can simply install an up to date JDK to a local directory, no "global" installation required. On Linux you can get a `.tar.gz` and I'm sure there's something similar for Windows (though I don't know what it would be, you'd need to search for that)

Comment: *"I also would like to avoid reprogramming my whole project with Java 8"* -> Maybe all it takes is rebuilding with 1.8 as target. Are you using newer APIs in your code? But the first solution is that if you are not a superuser on the server, get a superuser to install Java 11 for you.

Comment: AFAIK: An older java version can **never** run a program which was compiled with a newer version.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I suppose the `.tar.gz` you mentioned are found on https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html . Would you happen to know the command I'd need to use once I have this `.tar.gz` file?

Comment: @J.Schmidt: a `.tar.gz` is just the unix-world equivalent of a zip file (technically a bit different, but that's irrelevant here). `tar xvzf thefile.tar.gz` will unpack it into the current directory.

Comment: @Lino You can make a newer Java compiler emit a jar following an older classfile specification, just as ernest_k suggested. That works if the sources don't use any of the newer language or API features.

Comment: you might want to check SDKMAN: https://sdkman.io/

Comment: @JoachimSauer Your answer worked out. If you like, post it as an answer. I can add the last step, which is after extracting use the command `newlyExtractedTarGzFolder/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, multiple solutions exist. I found the easiest were the following two solutions:

- Ask the server's super users to install Java 11.
- Download `jdk-11.0.11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html, which can be copied onto the server with `scp jdk-11.0.11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz serverName:.` Unpack with `tar xvzf jdk-11.0.11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` on the server and then execute your jar file with `jdk-11.0.11_linux-x64_bin.bin.java -jar file.jar`

I ended up asking the super users to install Java 11, which they told me was already installed at `someFolder/java11/bin/java`, so I ended up using `someFolder/java11/bin/java -jar file.jar`

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the source code of `file.jar`, you could try and create a jar for java 8 from it. If it fails, then there are some newer features used. You can go through the code and manually downgrade it.

Another option would be to ship a local installation (no superuser rights required) of java with the software.